# Replace input with another one without the need of 6 helpers

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas

Can anyone bring some light on the following: I'm able to get the expected results, but I need 6 helpers for that, which is too much:

**Spreadsheet**: [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T8e_Dg_8W2BTrrLi_NaCHsXW0_ULJSAEo40n35KBcng/edit#gid=616832096)

[image]

So I have for example the following input: `21-FI-3040506.High`, and the desired output would be: `21-FAH-3040506`

To achieve that, I use 6 helpers:

**First**: extract what's after the dot
`=INDEX(SPLIT(A2, "."), , 2)`

**Second**: extract what's between the 2nd dash and the dot (which is a 7 digits most of the time, but in few cases it's followed by a single letter like 3040570A)
`=INDEX(SPLIT(INDEX(SPLIT(A2, "."), , 1),"-"), , 3)`

**Third**: conditions on the second helper: `=IF(B2="High","AH",If(B2="HighHigh","AHH",IF(B2="Low","AL",If(B2="LowLow","ALL","A"))))`

**Fourth**: extract what's between the 2 dashes
`=INDEX(SPLIT(A2, "-"), , 2)`

**Fifth**: conditional substitute on the 3rd helper
`=IF(D2="A",SUBSTITUTE(E2,"I","T"), SUBSTITUTE(E2,"I",D2))`

**Sixth**: extract number before the first dash
`=INDEX(SPLIT(A2, "-"), , 1)`

Then I would concatenate the different results to obtain the desired result.
`=IF(D2="A",CONCATENATE(G2,"-",F2,"-",C2,".",B2),CONCATENATE(G2,"-",F2,"-",C2))`

Anyone would help me to simplify the task, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(
 REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "Fail"), 
 REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "I-", "T-"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+")&"-"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+-(.+)I-")&"A"&
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\.(.+)"), "[a-z]+", )&"-"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "-(\d+.?|\d+-\d+)\."))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Great and neat work as usual.